# Variable.split() command problems

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program where the user inputs a word from a sentence given to them, and my code would give them the position the word was in. For example, if the user were to type in the word 'pizza' my code should respond by outputting "4th position". I am new to python so all help would be highly appreciated!
All i have so far:

```
food = "i love Italian pizza"
food2 = food.split()
for x in list(food2)
```

Comment: You can use `list`'s `.index()` function to find an item in list.

Comment: be careful. `.index()` raises an error when the item is not present. `.find()`will just return -1. So depending on whether or not you expect it to be there you should use the appropriate method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  With your existing code you can do this:

```
# Query the user:
word = str(raw_input("Enter Word: "))

food = "i love Italian pizza"
food2 = food.split()
for (num, x) in enumerate(list(food2)):
  if word == x:
    print num
```

where:

- enumerate converts the list to tuples (0, "i"), (1, "love"), (2, "Italian"), (3 , "pizza")

Comment: Sorry if this is late but is there any way that i can give the numbers given a suffix like 'rd' for 3 and 'nd' for 2?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is list.index()

```
food = "i love Italian pizza"
food2 = food.split()
index = food2.index("Italian")
print str(index + 1) + " position"
```

Put the variable with the user input where "Italian" is.

For user input:

```
try:
  c = raw_input('Enter Word: ')
  index = food2.index(c)
  print str(index + 1) + " position"
except ValueError as E:
  print "Not in list"
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
food = "i love Italian pizza"
print food.split().index("pizza") + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it like this:

```
def test():
    words = 'i love Italian pizza'.split()
    word = str(raw_input())

    if word in words:
        print 'position = ', words.index(word)+1
    else:
        print 'word not found'
```